# Generate ObjC code using LLVM

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, llvm

I have been reading [this](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-04-24-code-generation-with-llvm-part-2-fast-objective-c-forwarding.html) article on implementing fast forwarding in Objective C using LLVM and had an idea for doing something similar. Is it possible to generate Objective C code to extend an existing class using LLVM? I have a class definition. Now I want to add a new message to that class using LLVM. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do this with the Runtime library, add methods etc....[Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)

Look at...

```
BOOL class_addMethod(Class cls, SEL name, IMP imp, const char *types)
```